# How to change android flavors build order

Tags: android, jenkins, gradle

I have two flavors in my android project, and i know that gradle build the flavors in alphabetical order, Is there any way to change this order??

Comment: Why do you want to define the order? The answer to this might influence the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

If they are built alphabetically, this is - even if deterministic - just a coincidence, at least as much as Gradle is involved. If the Android plugin defines that order that's another topic, but I don't think so.

You can easily define the order of tasks without introducing dependencies from one to the other so that they can still be run individually by using `shouldRunAfter` and `mustRunAfter`. The latter guarantees the order, the former only guarantees the order as long as no parallel task processing is done which is an incubating Gradle feature.